# Using Union on the same subselect

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery, union

```
SELECT "a" as var1, foo FROM (SELECT foo FROM table1) as a 
UNION`  
SELECT "b" as var1, foo FROM (SELECT foo FROM table1) as b
```

Can I change this UNION to only do the sub select once?

I am asking because currently this looks stupid and for large table1 or more complex sub selects (this is just a minimal example) there is potential for make the computation time better.

I tried this, which would look like what i want but doesn't work:

```
SELECT "a" as var1, per FROM (SELECT per FROM selectpers) as a
UNION SELECT "b" as var1, per FROM a
```

Comment: Can't you use a CTE? Providing some sample input data and the expected result would help people help you.

Comment: I suspect you have oversimplified..

Comment: What you have *shown* can simply be a union of the two derived columns with a cross join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT x.var1, table1.foo
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 'a' as var1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'b'
             ) x
```